# R How to use grid.curve to draw arc between two points

Tags: r

The code below draws an arc but not between the x,y points specified. What am I doing wrong?

```
library(grid)
rangex <- range(1,1000)
rangey <- range(1,1000)
plot(rangex, rangey,type="n", ann=F,ylim=c(1,1000))
x1=500
y1=500
x2=200
y2=200
grid.curve(x1,y1,x2,y2,default.units = "native")
```

Here is a better example. I am trying to draw a curve within a plot that has a ton of other stuff going on (represented by the line in the code below). But why are the points and curve not in exactly the correct spot?

```
library(grid)
rangex <- range(1,700)
rangey <- range(1,700)
data=c(200:500)
plot(rangex, rangey,type="n", ann=F,ylim=c(1,700))
x1=500
y1=500
x2=200
y2=200
lines(data,data)
pushViewport(dataViewport(rangex, rangey))
grid.curve(x1,y1,x2,y2,default.units = "native")
grid.points(x1,y1,pch=20)
grid.points(x2,y2,pch=20)
popViewport()
```

Comment: you seem to be mixing base and grid graphics. Once you sort this you can use `pushViewport(dataViewport(rangex, rangey))` before the `grid.curve`

Comment: See my additional example

Comment: you are using plot, and lines in your second example - these are base r functions: try `grid.newpage() ; 
pushViewport(plotViewport(c(5.1, 4.1, 4.1, 2.1))) ; 
pushViewport(dataViewport(rangex, rangey)) ; 
grid.xaxis() ; grid.yaxis() ;
grid.curve(x1,y1,x2,y2,default.units = "native") ;
grid.points(x1,y1,pch=20) ;
grid.points(x2,y2,pch=20)` . Taken from  example in page 12 from first doc *grid*:  https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grid/html/grid-package.html

Answer (score 0):

A bit late in the day but this may be useful for others.

The key to this seems to be to set `grid.curve` arguments as follows:

1. `square = FALSE` - allows for a smooth curve.
2. `curvature = arcCurvature(theta = n)` to control the radius of the arc by reference to theta: the angle subtended from the centre of the circle to the two arc points in degrees.
3. `ncp = n` to control the smoothness of the arc, i.e. the number of points which make up the arc. The function documentation mentions use of a "large `npc`" but does not define "large". So you may need to experiment a bit with this.

I've added a second arc just to illustrate managing the placement of the arc centre and different arc radii.

```r
library(grid)
rangex <- range(1,700)
rangey <- range(1,700)
data=c(200:500)
plot(rangex, rangey,type="n", ann=F,ylim=c(1,700))
x1=500
y1=500
x2=200
y2=200
lines(data,data)
pushViewport(dataViewport(rangex, rangey))
grid.curve(x1,y1,x2,y2,
           ncp = 50,
           square = FALSE,
           curvature = arcCurvature(theta = 60),
           default.units = "native")
grid.curve(x2,y2,x1,y1,
           ncp = 50,
           square = FALSE,
           curvature = arcCurvature(theta = 140),
           default.units = "native",
           gp = gpar(col = "red"))
grid.points(x1,y1,pch=20)
grid.points(x2,y2,pch=20)
popViewport()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2024-01-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>